# Keep station identifier with leading zero numeric

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame that comes from the United States Geological Survey (USGS) website, whom use leading zeros in their site identifier (`site_no`). I need to maintain the leading zero in the `site_no` in order to do further analysis; the catch is that `site_no` needs to be class numeric NOT character. Below is an example data frame that mimics the issue.

```
df1 <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = 20))
x <- c("site_no", "Date", "Wtemp")
colnames(df1) <- x
df1$site_no <- c("0101","0101","0101","0101","0101",
                "0102","0102","0102","0102","0102",
                "0103","0103","0103","0103","0103",
                "104","104","104","104","104")
df1$Date <- rep(seq(from = as.Date("2020-01-01"), to = as.Date("2020-01-05"), by = 1),4)  
df1$Wtemp <- c(10,NA,NA,NA,15,
               20,NA,NA,10,16,
               2,4,6,8,10,
               12,14,16,18,20)
```

I have tried the following with no success

```
df1$site_no <- as.numeric(df1$site_no) # makes numeric but drops the leading zero which needs to be maintained
```

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(site_no = ifelse(row_number()<=15, paste0("0", site_no), site_no)) # returns the leading zero but makes class character
```

Comment: Numeric values simply cannot have "leading zeros". That's purely a character formatting thing. If you need both leading values and zeros, then you should store the value twice as character and numeric. Or just do the conversion only as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

An option is `comma` from `formattable`

```
library(dplyr)
library(formattable)
out <- df1 %>%
        mutate(site_no = comma(as.numeric(site_no), 
       width = 4, flag = '0', digits = 0, f = 'd', big.mark = ''))
is.numeric(out$site_no)
#[1] TRUE

out$site_no
#[1] 0101 0101 0101 0101 0101 0102 0102 0102 0102 0102 0103 0103 0103 0103 0103 0104 0104 0104 0104 0104

sum(out$site_no)
#[1] 2050
```

-output

```
out
#   site_no       Date Wtemp
#1     0101 2020-01-01    10
#2     0101 2020-01-02    NA
#3     0101 2020-01-03    NA
#4     0101 2020-01-04    NA
#5     0101 2020-01-05    15
#6     0102 2020-01-01    20
#7     0102 2020-01-02    NA
#8     0102 2020-01-03    NA
#9     0102 2020-01-04    10
#10    0102 2020-01-05    16
#11    0103 2020-01-01     2
#12    0103 2020-01-02     4
#13    0103 2020-01-03     6
#14    0103 2020-01-04     8
#15    0103 2020-01-05    10
#16    0104 2020-01-01    12
#17    0104 2020-01-02    14
#18    0104 2020-01-03    16
#19    0104 2020-01-04    18
#20    0104 2020-01-05    20
```

---

Or an option to keep the column as `numeric` would be create `label` attribute

```
library(labelled)
out <- df1 %>%
   mutate(site_no = as.numeric(site_no), 
          site_no = labelled(site_no, setNames(unique(site_no), 
          str_pad(unique(site_no), width = 4, pad = '0')))) 

str(out)
#'data.frame':  20 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ site_no: dbl+lbl [1:20] 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 103, 103, #103, 103, 103, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104
#   ..@ labels: Named num  101 102 103 104
#   .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "0101" "0102" "0103" "0104"
# $ Date   : Date, format: "2020-01-01" "2020-01-02" "2020-01-03" "2020-01-04" ...
# $ Wtemp  : num  10 NA NA NA 15 20 NA NA 10 16 ...
```

---

Or we can keep it as `character` by using  `str_pad`

```
library(stringr)    
df1 %>%
   mutate(site_no = str_pad(site_no, width = 4, pad = '0'))
```

-output

```
#   site_no       Date Wtemp
#1     0101 2020-01-01    10
#2     0101 2020-01-02    NA
#3     0101 2020-01-03    NA
#4     0101 2020-01-04    NA
#5     0101 2020-01-05    15
#6     0102 2020-01-01    20
#7     0102 2020-01-02    NA
#8     0102 2020-01-03    NA
#9     0102 2020-01-04    10
#10    0102 2020-01-05    16
#11    0103 2020-01-01     2
#12    0103 2020-01-02     4
#13    0103 2020-01-03     6
#14    0103 2020-01-04     8
#15    0103 2020-01-05    10
#16    0104 2020-01-01    12
#17    0104 2020-01-02    14
#18    0104 2020-01-03    16
#19    0104 2020-01-04    18
#20    0104 2020-01-05    20
```

---

Or with `sprintf` from `base R` after converting to numeric

```
df1$site_no <- with(df1, sprintf('%04d', as.numeric(site_no)))
```

Comment: Both of these methods above return ```class(df1$site_no)``` as "character", I'm looking for "numeric" if possible.

Comment: @tassones can you check the updated solution